# Passing $(sysconfdir) to Source Code from Autoconf/Automake

Tags: c, gcc, autoconf, automake

I'm quite frustrated.  I'm trying to pass the name of the system configuration directory to a source file as a symbol.  Some research on this very site gave me to understand that I should add the line

```
AM_CPPFLAGS = -DSYSCONFIR='$(sysconfdir)'
```

to my Makefile.am.  I did so, and the define does show up in the invocation of gcc; in fact, here it is:

```
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../src -I..  -DSYSCONFIR='/usr/etc'   -g -O2 -MT perm.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/perm.Tpo -c -o perm.o ../../src/perm.c
```

The trouble is, gcc barfs anyway, telling me that SYSCONFDIR is undeclared.

I've got to be doing something wrong, but for the love of St. Gulik, I don't know what it is.  My autoconf is 2.68, my automake is 1.11.3, my gcc is 4.6.3, and I'm trying to do this under Ubuntu 12.04.

A clean compile, a clean compile!  My kingdom for a clean compile!

Comment: To improve the visual layout of this question, add four spaces to the start of lines containing terminal commands. This will then format them differently to make them easier to read

Comment: If an answer solves your issue you might like to mark it as such by clicking the answer's check-mark.

Answer (score 3):

What you show looks like typo.

You are setting and passing `SYSCONFIR` which is not the same as `SYSCONFDIR`.